# Discord.py bot - how to make bot copy my message

Tags: python, discord, bots

I'm developing in Python. I'd like to make my bot copying the previous message, which contains a special command for this.

For example, I type the command `say`. So it would look like this:

> **Me:** say What are you doing?

> **Bot:** What are you doing?

Comment: What have you tried so far? It always helps if you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: To tell the truth, I don't have any idea, so it's the reason why I asked :(. 
I tried @Seekii's code:

```@bot.listen()
async def on_message(message):

    if message.content.startswith("!say"):

        await message.channel.send(message.content)```

It IS showing the right result but one minus is that the bot says ```!say``` command too, but shouldn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@bot.listen()
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith("!say"):
        await message.channel.send(message.content)
```

Comment: It is really helpful but now it copies the whole command. I mean my bot is saying the command too. Is there is any way to delete ```!say``` from bot's message?

Comment: @Aaron try `echo = message.content.split(" ", 1)[1]` and `await message.channel.send(echo)`

Answer (score 1):

This work for me:

```
@bot.command()
async def say(ctx,*,args): 
    await ctx.send(args)
```

Comment: The problem is that I type my bot as every command with ```if```, and not ```async```, so it just shows an error. Don't You know, how to reformat it into ```if``` type?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @UziGoozie comment and @Seekii code, the solution to this problem is the next code:

```
async def on_message(message):
    echo = message.content.split(" ", 1)[1]
    if message.content.startswith("!say"):
    await message.channel.send(echo)
```